# A reference for geometric class field theory?

Tags: reference-request, class-field-theory, ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-groups, textbook-recommendation

The classic reference of this topic is Serre's Algebraic Groups and Class Fields.  However, many parts of this book use Weil's language, which I find quite hard to follow.  Is there another reference to the topic, using a more modern language (schemes etc.)?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Have you looked at

1. [Katz-Lang](http://www.math.princeton.edu/%7Enmk/old/AbsFinThm.pdf)
2. [Conrad's write-up](http://math.stanford.edu/%7Econrad/249BW09Page/handouts/geomcft.pdf)
3. [Lang's BAMS article](http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.bams/1183548780)
4. [Ben-Zvi's notes](http://www.msri.org/realvideo/ln/msri/2002/introstacks/ben-zvi/1/index.html) (i seem to remember a video, but i could not find it.) also see [his other lectures and videos](http://www.math.utexas.edu/users/benzvi/Langlands.html)
5. [Thesis of Peter Toth](https://dspace.library.uu.nl/bitstream/handle/1874/206061/TothPeterMA2011.pdf)  (follows Deligne's approach)
6. [Kerz's articles](http://arxiv.org/find/math/1/au%3A+Kerz_M/0/1/0/all/0/1) (amazing innovations in class field theory by Kerz and Wiesend); there is also an excellent Seminaire Bourbaki expose on this by Szamuely (in French).

There are many other good references, but hope this can help.

Comment: I just saw Elencwajg's reply; sorry for the duplicates in my reply.
@Elenvwajg: glad to find myself often in your good company!

Comment: Many many thanks for the very good recommendations.

Answer (score 25):

1) Our  (slightly pseudonymous!)  friend, Brian Conrad, has written this beautiful [introduction](http://math.stanford.edu/~conrad/249BW09Page/handouts/geomcft.pdf) to geometric class field theory in his characteristically lucid style.

2) Another  friend, Péter Tóth, has just written a Master Thesis [*"Geometric Abelian Class Field Theory"*](http://dspace.library.uu.nl/bitstream/handle/1874/206061/TothPeterMA2011.pdf) which seems to be what you are looking for: it is geometric and contains all necessary prerequisites. And the author writes in his abstract that he wants *"...to remedy the unfortunate situation that the literature on this topic is very deficient, partial and sketchy written..."*.

3) David Ben-Zvi, a well-known specialist and another friend of ours,  gave talks on Geometric Langlands at MSRI in 2002, and part I is on geometric class field theory. Here is a [link](http://www.msri.org/realvideo/ln/msri/2002/introstacks/ben-zvi/1/banner/01.html)

I am very happy and proud that all the specialists mentioned above are members of and active contributors to our site.

Comment: These are very valuable. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Also notice Avichai Tendler's [Master's Thesis](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1507.00104) at the Hebrew University of Jerusalem, and several other links that are returned by a web search with the terms "geometric abelian class field theory".

Answer (score 4):

I have seen Section e) of the letter from Deligne to Serre available at http://www.math.uni-bonn.de/people/richarz/DeligneAnSerreFeb74.pdf mentioned as a reference. I have not read it myself and it is hand written (in French), but it might be what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation. Unfortunately, I don't know any French, which makes reading handwriting pretty much impossible.

Comment: Can’t find anything following the link?

Comment: It is available [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20150330055922/http://www.math.uni-bonn.de/people/richarz/DeligneAnSerreFeb74.pdf).

Answer (score 1):

There is also Milne's Arithmetic Duality Theorems, http://jmilne.org/math/Books/ADTnot.pdf p. 126ff., Appendix I.A. He proves local and global class field theory using algebraic geometry and Galois cohomology.

Answer (score 1):

In the appendix to chapter I of [Pursuing stacks](https://arxiv.org/abs/2111.01000), Grothendieck writes:

> A large part of the letter outlines (very sketchily) some main points of a duality program (including a cohomological formulation of “geometric” local
> and global class field theory), which emerged by the end of the fifties
> and appears here for the first time in print.

For example App 12 is entitled *"Global “geometric” class field theory as a cohomological duality formula. Serre duality and the “Lang trick”."* and 13 *"Case of local “geometric” class field theory."*

Hope this helps!